# Can I let a widget overflow the screen on the side in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, user-interface

[Visual Description of what I wanna do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/femXP.png)
I'm wondering if there is a way to move half of a widget behind the screen, so that you can still one
half and than left to it there would be a nice text.
But currently if I try to do that it sais that its a overflow.
Is there anyway that I can achieve this effect?

I tried Transform.translate with an Offset but it didnt work at all.
And it gave me the error.

EDIT:
Is fixed here is how i did it:

```
class _NewMenuState extends State<NewMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(50, 50),
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: HomePage(),
            ))
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What error did using `Transform.translate` give you? Could you post the code of what you tried, it would be a helpful base for people to provide you with an answer.

Comment: class _NewMenuState extends State<NewMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Transform.translate(offset: Offset(50, 50), child: HomePage())
      ],
    ));
  }
}  //HomePage is just a Container

Comment: issue is fixed i just had to wrap HomePage with another Container with height and width